# Change version of vim used by mutt

Tags: vim, mutt

When I edit mails in mutt (OS X 10.12.3), the vim version I get is the one compiled by root@apple.com. When I start vim from the terminal I get the one compiled by Homebrew, which is the one I want (has +clipboard). How do I make sure that mutt uses this one too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix: Added the following to .muttrc:

```
set editor="vim"
```